# Chrome extension: get current Profile's Person's username

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple extension for Chrome.

There's an option for user to set a Profile Name

[image: Profile Person name]

How to get that name "lan" in the extension?

It's a really simple extension

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": .."description"...
    ...
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    ...
}
```

**background.js**

```
// how to get the profile name here?
// chrome.what.user.profile.name??
```

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I'm also looking to get Chrome "person" data for my extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question, but I'm afraid the answer is that currently there is no API to access that information.

Comment: I've created a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=504815

Comment: Really? That's too bad. Thanks for submitting a feature request.

Comment: This answer is 4 years old now.  I'm trying to write an extension that gets the local Chrome username (where a user is not logged into Chrome).  Was anything ever added to Chrome API to allow me to do this?  I just want the extension to be able to differentiate one user over another.

Comment: @Jstation, extensions are installed separately by each browser profile. One specific installation of your extension will never be under more than one profile. So, there no need to do what you want.

Comment: @GetFree No need is wrong. I have an extension sending out a file to a server. The server should know from which of my profiles this file is coming. So I need the name of the profile in the extension.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog, that problem is easy to solve. When the extension is installed, generate a unique ID string and save it on permanent storage. Now you can identify each installation of your extension uniquely.

Comment: @GetFree Of course, yes, but this is hardly zero-config and not convenient. The point is we need an access to profile name if we want to access this and avoid chrome sign-in requirements.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog, You have to work with the tools you have available. You can't get the user profile name, so the next best thing is just to create an unique identifier and problem solved.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog Perhaps you could add your voice in the feature request linked in the first comment. Describe your use-case there.

Comment: Have you looked into https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/ or https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/instanceID/?